# Creating simulation in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, opengl, xna

IDE: VS 2010, C#, .net 4.0

I have a requirement where I need to simulate object in isometric view.

Input parameter initial point start(x, y) of object, end point end(x,y). the object path. you can see following video for example

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAcDqCS7Ur8
```

In this video you can assume ball as object o, bowler is releasing ball from start(x, y) points ball is pitching on a zone z. and on some angle it is pitching up, so Is it possible to simulate same thing in visual studio, if yes please let me know what techniques can be used, As I researched xna, opengl or directx can be used, what will be easiest and best to achieve this goal, so I can embed this with my winforms application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try studying a *Physics Engine*. There is some implementation available for c#, google for it and find some that you think is good for you. Basically with a physics engine you can define bodies and forces applied to them, and have the position time by time.

Comment: so before starting "Physics Engine", should I study basics of XNA..?

Comment: @yogeshkmrsoni  not necessarily, Physics engine are generally independent from the graphical platform.